# The order in which ld-linux.so executes CTORs?

Tags: c, linker, elf

I know it's related to the order in which shared objects are specified in the linker command line, i.e. if you do this:

`gcc -o main main.c -lA -lB`

The CTORs in libB will run before the ones in libA.

Is this behavior standardized? Can I make use of it in a framework that is meant to be portable between hardware platforms?

P.S. A CTOR is a function with the `__attribute__((constructor))` stuff.

Comment: An application that depends on this is extremely fragile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application that depends on this is extremely fragile... Also a number of people consider *any* use of global constructors, especially in C, a major offense and grounds for not using a library. `pthread_once` provides a much cleaner way to get the same safe initialization without programmers using your library having to worry that you may have messed up the program's initial state before `main` is entered.

Comment: I see. The `pthread_once` way is indeed cleaner, but it induces a library dependency. I just found out that iptables uses the `__attribute__((constructor))` way to initialize extensions, I may keep digging into the source to see how it handles/avoids the ordering problem.

Comment: `iptables` is not good code to model your program on. It's just about the worst abuse of shared libraries for *no purpose* I've ever seen, and thereby makes its runtimes *several times* slower than it should be, hurting startup performance of firewalls greatly.

Comment: Also, I would not call `pthread` a library dependency. `pthread` is as much a part of the standard library on POSIX as `stdio` or the math functions. The fact that `stdio` is contained in `libc.so` on most systems, while math functions are in a separate `libm.so` and pthread functions in a separate `libpthread.so`, is purely an artifact of legacy implementation choices...

Comment: Well, iptables doesn't care about the ordering at all....I have tested the constructors in GCC 3.4.4 & 4.1.0, the 2 versions have exactly the same behavior. But since this behavior is not standardized, I shall just ignore it and figure out something else. Thx for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

All the `__attribute__` mechanism is a gcc specific extension. So in consequence this is not standardized.

C by itself doesn't have the concept of dynamic constructors of variables with static storage or things like that. The only thing it has is initialization of such variable with compile constant expressions.

There are a number of tools in POSIX threads that work around this. R.. already mentioned `pthread_once`. `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` have macros that evaluate to a constant expression. By that they can thus be used as initializer for variables in global scope.